# Работа с 7zip.dll

Tags: windows, библиотеки, c++, zip

Всем привет. Понадобилось прикрутить к своей программе возможность распаковки множества форматов архивов. Выбор пал на 7zip.dll из-за ее всеядности и LGPL'ности.

В общем и целом, как с нею работать я понял, но мне очень нужна одна функция - возможность распаковать архив (не весь, а только один файл) **не на диск, а в выделенный буфер в памяти**. Кто-нибудь уже изощрялся подобным образом? Или может есть другая какая-нибудь библиотека, столь же всеядня и LGPL'ная?

Очень не хочется лезть в глубины 7zip'овского кода, так же не хочется самому заморачиваться со всеми форматами (а чем больше форматов поддерживается, тем лучше)

Comment: Речь про [LZMA SDK][1]?

 [1]:http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: Не совсем, как я понял, lzma sdk поддерживает только одноименную компрессию, а 7zip.dll поддерживает все форматы, которые поддерживает 7z

Comment: А где можно посмотреть интерфейс 7zip.dll?

Comment: В исходниках есть примеры работы с нею. Лежат в CPP\7zip\UI

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/forums/forum/45797/topic/5125577

Answer (score -1):

Нужно использовать опцию записи в стандартный поток вывода

```
7z e archive.zip -so file_name
```

В своей программе нужно перехватывать данные с потока вывода и записывать их в буфер

```
    std::string out_data;
    fflush(stdout);
    FILE* fd = popen("7z e archive.zip -so file_name", "r");
    if (fd != nullptr) {
        char buf[10];
        for (int r = 0; (r = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fd)) > 0;) {
            out_data.append(static_cast<const char*>(buf), r);
        }
        pclose(fd);
    }
```